# What is this green wire on my dryer for?

Tags: dryer

I recently bought a used washing machine and dryer and am in the process of hooking them up. What should I do with this green wire attached to the back of the drier?

[image]

Edit:

- The dryer, a Kenmore 80 series, has a plug with 3 prongs
- The house is a 1970s mobile home, and the outlet also has three prongs

Comment: It is a ground wire, supposed to help to keep you from lighting up like a christmas tree, if hooked up properly.  See warning label.  Don't know dryer so do not know if that is extra or needs to be placed somewhere.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? If so, unplug the dryer and check (a) for continuity between the end of the green wire and any bare metal on the case and (b) for continuity between the neutral pin (just check them all...) of the plug and the green wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an independent ground wire that someone added and then disconnected at one end.  Judging from the size, it would be totally inadequate.  I would remove it.